# How do I get my Address ModelForm not to raise an exception when a field is left blank?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here's the form:

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    postal_code = CharField()
    city = CharField()
    province = CharField()
    country = CharField()

    def clean_postal_code(self):
        postal_code = self.cleaned_data['postal_code'].strip().upper()
        if not re.match(r'^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$', postal_code):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid postal code.')
        return ' '.join((postal_code[:3], postal_code[-3:]))

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data

        if 'country' in data:
            data['country'] = Country.objects.get_or_create(name=data['country'])[0]
            if 'province' in data:
                data['province'] = Province.objects.get_or_create(name=data['province'], country=data['country'])[0]
                if 'city' in data:
                    data['city'] = City.objects.get_or_create(name=data['city'], province=data['province'])[0]
                    if 'postal_code' in data:
                        data['postal_code'] = PostalCode.objects.get_or_create(code=data['postal_code'], city=data['city'])[0]

        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

Everything is normalized into separate tables, but I don't want to use `<select>` boxes because there could be hundreds of thousands of entries. So instead, I'm using `CharFields` and then I'll use auto-complete with it.

Problem is if something like the `country` field is left blank, then that whole chunk of code inside `clean()` never gets ran, and then the fields never get converted to their appropriate types. Thus, I get an exception like this:

> Cannot assign "u'A1B 2C3'": "Address.postal_code" must be a "PostalCode" instance.

I was hoping that since the `clean()` process technically didn't pass (country is a required field) it wouldn't check for that. Now I don't know how to avoid it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Wow! This is a surprisingly difficult problem. I must have hit 10 road blocks.

**if you don't need unique together validation** (which you're not doing in your modelform anyways): I think the easiest solution is to exclude your model fields, override the `save`, and manually apply the cleaned data to `self.instance`. Let the regular form validation do the cleaning.

```
skip_model_validation_fields =  \
    ('country','province','city','postal_code')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for field in self.skip_model_validation_fields:
        setattr(self.instance, field, self.cleaned_data.get(field))

    return super(MyForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Address
    exclude = self.skip_model_validation_fields
```

If you need unique_together you could manually run `self.unique_together()` but at that point you would also need to capture the error, re-display form, etc...

So maybe a new suggestion is to use forms instead of hackishly dealing with `ModelForm`. Sounds like the aid is no longer an aid!

---

The problem is that even if you raise `forms.ValidationError` inside `clean()` an instance is created and fields from `cleaned_data` are set to that instance regardless.

Moving your validation to per-field would work but will be a pain because your validation has a hierarchy and you'd need to define the hierarchy in each fields clean method.

PostalCode depends on City, City depends on Province... etc or else risk running into the same error

You could delete items directly from cleaned_data in your `clean()` function but that too will be a royal pain for the same reason above.

I learned a ton about ModelForms today...

Comment: Haha...yeah, I spent hours going down all those different paths too. You can't put them into separate clean methods, because apparently they're not run in any particular order. Can't delete the items because then it'll display error messages beside each field saying they're required, even though the user actually did fill something in. I actually *do* have a bunch of unique_together conditions on all those fields, but I don't think it'll be an issue because with the way it's set up, no dupes should ever be created. I'll try your approach,but I'm pretty much ready to throw Django out the window

Comment: Wow yeah, I had no idea it would be so hard. Technically, the `clean_FOO` methods are run in the order they are defined, but for ModelForms it looks like it's the order the Model was defined because they are auto created. You're right, that would be a little confusing to delete the items. You could silently delete from cleaned_data and ensure only the empty field throws a validation error but that's a ton of code. I think you've just run into a situation where a regular form would have been faster!